# How to use matplotlib to plot complex bar graphs–multiple subplots with multiple rows of bars?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a sample dataframe like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(
    0, 10, size=(1000, 11)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'))
```

The desired but unpolished output looks like this:

**The data of each column in the dataframe is plotted as a subplot with five rows of bars.**

[image]

I prefer to use matplotlib because I can relatively easily make the graphs looking good. But its performance seems pretty slow.

Comment: How are you plotting?

Comment: @gcoronel99 I generate this graph using pyqtgraph, but I'm not very familiar with the the package.

Comment: Are you open to using Seaborn?

Comment: @gcoronel99 Yes! That's even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `bottom` parameter of [`bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib-axes-axes-bar) to offset the individual rows.
The following not optimized example demonstrates this approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1000, 11)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'))

fig = plt.figure()

for i,c in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 4, i+1)
    for x,h,b in zip((df.index.to_numpy() % 200).reshape(-1, 200), df[c].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 200), (df.index.to_numpy() // 200 * 10).reshape(-1, 200)):
        ax.set_title(c)
        ax.bar(x, h, bottom=b, color='k' )
```

[image]